# Number of roots of the equation $\sum_{i=1}^{2020}\frac{i^2}{x-i}=0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

What is the number of roots of the equation $\sum_{i=1}^{2020}\frac{i^2}{x-i}=0$?

I suspect that the equation has a single root. This is my guess based on the observation that we could choose some integer $x$ from $1$ to $2020$ so that the positive part of sum cancels with the negative part of the sum. But, the problem, is we are allowed to choose any real values for $x$. The function is not a polynomial. So, how should I proceed? Is intermediate value theorem helpful here? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Put it over a common denominator.  What is the degree of the numerator?

Comment: @vidyarthi The intermediate value theorem is not applicable because the function is not continuous.

Comment: @PierreCarre but the answer below uses intermediate value piecewise!

Comment: @vidyarthi Yes, because the function is continuous in each interval $(i, i+1)$. It is not directly applicable in the whole domain.

Comment: @user2661923 yes, that is. But, still the function takes zero several times

Comment: @vidyarthi are you preparing yourself for NBHM PhD screening test?

Comment: @Phibetakappa yes, I was preparing, but now, mostly I would skip the exam due to COVID, how about you?

Comment: This year I will sit for this exam. Where are you from?

Comment: @Phibetakappa Bangalore, you?

Comment: I am from Kolkata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that $f$ has vertical asymptotes at $x = 1,2,3, \cdots, 2020$ and that at each interval $[i, i+1]$ the function is strictly monotone and takes any real value.

This means that the equation has exactly one solution in each interval $[i, i+1]$, $i = 1, \cdots, 2019$.

Finally, since the function is negative for $x<1$ and positive for $x>2020$, we can conclude that the equation has exactly 2019 solutions in its domain of definition.

Comment: The terms are all positive for $x\gt 2020$ and all negative for $x\lt 1$

Comment: @Empy2 Yes, I kind of left it hanging.